# module 'cv2.ximgproc' has no attribute 'getDisparityVis'

Tags: python, camera, opencv, stereo-3d

I am trying to do postprocessing the disparity map in Opencv. While using '''getDisparityVis''' in the code it throwing following error.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
filtered_disp_vis= cv2.ximgproc.getDisparityVis(disparity,filtered_disp_vis,1.0);
```

Error

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1594f6523e20> in <module>

 27         dispr = np.int16(right_disp)

 28         disparity = wls_filter.filter(left_disp, fixedLeft, None, right_disp)
---> 29         ximgproc.getDisparityVis(disparity,filtered_disp_vis,1.0);

 30 
 31         cv2.imshow('leftImage',displ/1.0)

AttributeError: module 'cv2.ximgproc' has no attribute 'getDisparityVis'
```

Comment: what did you try to investigate the issue?

Comment: please provide the version of OpenCV you are using

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz Sorry for the late reply. To am currently using OpenCV version 4.4.0.46 and Python 3.9

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz For debugging I tried using a different version of OpenCV 4.3.0.36 and then again run the program but the error persists

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz Could you please guide me to any sample code which is using 'getDisparityVis'

Comment: as far as I can see, getDisparityVis only recently (in v4.5) received its python binding. you need to use at least v4.5 of OpenCV.

Comment: Okay, Thank you I will look into it

Comment: Did you come to an answer? I'm coming to the same problem and I see that `opencv-contrib-python` is only [sitting at version 4.4](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/releases). I still can't seem to access `getDisparityVis` with the most recent release.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this function is **very** [simple](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/b91a781cbc1285d441aa682926d93d8c23678b0b/modules/ximgproc/src/disparity_filters.cpp#L559), and all you need to do in Python is create a similar function. This was my solution:

```py
def get_disparity_vis(src: np.ndarray, scale: float = 1.0) -> np.ndarray:
    '''Replicated OpenCV C++ function

    Found here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/b91a781cbc1285d441aa682926d93d8c23678b0b/modules/ximgproc/src/disparity_filters.cpp#L559
    
    Arguments:
        src (np.ndarray): input numpy array
        scale (float): scale factor

    Returns:
        dst (np.ndarray): scaled input array
    '''
    dst = (src * scale/16.0).astype(np.uint8)
    return dst
```